# RenderPartial missing from Html Helper in ASP.NET MVC 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I've just converted an application from MVC 1 to MVC 2 using the VS2010 wizard. Not found is the Html.RenderPartial which I have sprinkled around a number of views. I am guessing that this is something that I've done wrong because I see no mention of this as a breaking change in the white papers and docs. Everything I'm using is RTM/RTW and no beta or RC versions.

EDIT: On closer inspection it looks like all the extension methods on the Html class are missing so I guess that I'm missing an include somewhere but I can't find it yet so any suggestions welcome...

Answer (score 3):

I think the location of these extensions has been moved to a different assembly. Try adding a reference to `System.Web.Mvc.Html`, and I think it should cover it.
Also make sure that VS has added the correct reference to the MVC library version 2, instead of the old v1 )

Answer (score 1):

What I did is to first convert from MVC1 to MVC2 with [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2010/03/10/migrating-asp-net-mvc-1-0-applications-to-asp-net-mvc-2-rtm.aspx). Then I used the Visual Studio 2010 to convert the project for 2010.

Most probably the Visual Studio wizard doesn't convert from MVC1 to MVC2.